# measure corresponding to certain orthogonal polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, orthogonal-polynomials

Given a scalar $\lambda\in (0,1)$, consider a sequence of monic polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}_{n\geq 0}$ over real variables satisfying the following recurrence relations:

$xp_n(x)=p_{n+1}(x)+\lambda p_{n}(x)+p_{n-1}(x)\;\;$   with
$p_0(x)\equiv1$ and  $p_1(x)\equiv x$.

We know that by Favard's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem), there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_\mathbb{R}p_n(x)p_m(x)d\mu(x)=0$ for all $n\neq m$ i.e. $\{p_n\}_{n\geq0}$ is an orthogonal sequence in $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu)$.

My question is: can we explicitly say what this measure $\mu$ is? I am more interested in knowing whether the measure is non-atomic. If not, can we locate its atoms?

This measure could be well-known but I could not find it in any book (e.g. https://books.google.co.in/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Orthogonal_Polynomial.html?id=71CVAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y).

Comment: If you rescale your polynomials by letting $y = (x-λ)/2$ then the recurrence relation becomes $p_{n+1} = 2y\,p_n - p_{n-1}$, which is the one satisfied by the [Čebyšëv polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), so they should be expressible as combination of $T_n$ and $U_n$ (of the variable $y$), for which the weight giving orthogonality is well-known.

Comment: To restate this (Gro-Tsen's comment) in spectral theoretic terms, $\lambda$ is irrelevant, you just shift the spectrum by $\lambda$, and then you are dealing with the (easy to analyze) free Jacobi matrix. In particular, its spectral measure is easy to find, and this is discussed in many sources. For example, try Teschl's book.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the scaling trick.